# iOS Swift date formatter returns nil

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdateformatter

I have a date string as follows, when I try to format it with the following date formatter it returns nil. The dateFormat checks. And when I try it on the nsdateformatter.com website it works. I can't wrap my head around it.

```
let dateString = "168.18:26:50.5783449"
let dateFormat = "d.HH:mm:ss"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

date is nil

Comment: you are missing milliseconds in your format (`.SSSSSSS`). You also need to use `D` (day of year) not `d` (day of month).

Comment: yeah I did that and it worked thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format would be `D.HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS`.

Note `D` for day of year instead of day of month.
Note the missing milliseconds pattern.

However, this date is not complete because it is missing the year therefore you don't have to get the date you expect.